# Unable to figure out runtime error in below program

Tags: c++, algorithm, sigabrt

I was solving [ArithmaticII](https://www.spoj.com/problems/ARITH2/).I am getting correct output for the below input

Input:
4

1 + 1 * 2 =

29 / 5 =

103 * 103 * 5 =

50 * 40 * 250 + 791 =

Output:

4

5

53045

500791

I am getting correct output ,But when i am submitting my solution to spoj , I
am getting runtime error as `SIGABRT` ,Due to the overflow issue I am using `stoll`,When i tried to debug my program everything was seemed to be running fine .

Note->It may also contain spaces to improve readability.

This line looks suspicious to me because my programs stops(runtime error) when i doesn't provide 
space in the input (1 * 1+2=)
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoll`
Please help where I am doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int t;
    string str;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {


        ///using cin.ignore() as input as preceded by a single line  
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, str, '\n');
        stringstream split(str);
        ///now use getline with specified delimeter to split string stream
        string intermediate;
        int flag = 0;
        long long int ans=1;
        while (getline(split, intermediate, ' ')) {
            if (intermediate == "=") {
                cout << ans<<"\n";
                break;

            }
            if (intermediate == "*") {
                flag = 1;
                continue;
            }
            else if (intermediate == "/") {
                flag = 2;
                continue;
            }
            else if (intermediate == "+") {
                flag = 3;
                continue;
            }
            else if(intermediate == "-"){
                flag = 4;
                continue;
            }
            if (flag == 1) {
                ans *= stoll(intermediate);
            }
            else if (flag == 2) {
                ans /= stoll(intermediate);
            }
            else if (flag == 3) {
                ans += stoll(intermediate);
            }
            else if (flag == 4) {
                ans -= stoll(intermediate);
            }
            else if (flag == 0) {
                ans = stoll(intermediate);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this implementation won't respect order of operations.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux from the example of `1 + 1 * 2 =` having the correct output of `4`, I'd guess that's what's wanted here.

Comment: operator which come first solved first in this case

Comment: dont you already know what is the problem? The input **may** contain spaces, but your code assumes the tokens are always seperated by space

Comment: I strongly recommend moving `cin.ignore();` to a better location. Preferably AFTER the operation that left a character in the stream. Placing the `ignore` before an operation on the chance that the previous operation left a character in the stream sets you up for surprises.

Comment: I found that while debugging invalid argument(space) is passing to stoi.But i how to avoid that .Please tell me where should i place those extra getlines in my code to take input safely.

Answer (score 0):

Using exactly the input you posted above:

```
4

1 + 1 * 2 =

29 / 5 =

103 * 103 * 5 =

50 * 40 * 250 + 791 =
```

I'm able to reproduce your error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>    what():  stoll
>   Aborted

I'll bet you removed the newlines in the sample input to simplify things--that's what it looks like from your code anyways. You're doing a `getline` and pulling exactly as many lines as you're told in the first input. That means you'll pull an empty line (`intermediate` will be an empty string) and you'll try to process it.

And what happens when you try to call `stoll("")`? The error you got!

You *could* try to check if you get an empty line and then continue, something like:

```
getline(cin, str, '\n');
if(str.empty()) {
    t++; //we didn't actually do anything, so increment t
    continue;
}
stringstream split(str);
...
```

Or, you could use the fact that the `>>` operator already stops when it hits whitespace (and eats all the whitespace it can to get to the next edible character). So instead of reading a line at a time, you could continue reading until you hit a `=` character.

Comment: But while taking input to `intermediate` using `getline ` I am specifying the delimeter
as white space.

Comment: so it will not to be taken as input inside intermediate variable  while processing the stream.

Comment: @akii121 Did you try running your code with the empty lines in the input string?

Comment: pease I tried using this http://spojtoolkit.com/history/ARITH2 test case I am still getting the same error,but when i remove extra getlines from my code it gives correct output,but does not pass on spoj  because input file contain extra lines

Comment: And i got your point But invalid argument is passing to `stoi` But how to avoid that?
now where to replace extra getlines in my code I am unable figure out.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> t;` does not eat the newline character after reading the number 4 from the input. As the program enters the loop `cin.ignore()` finishes the first line of the input and then `getline(...)` reads a blank line. You get an empty string which cannot be converted to an int.

Putting one more `cin.ignore()` after reading `t` fixes the runtime error.

You still have to handle the case when there are no spaces between the tokens. This requires rethinking the inner while loop:

```
long long int ans;
char op;
split >> ans;
while (split >> skipws >> op) {
    if (op == '=') {
        cout << ans << '\n';
        break;
    }
    long long int n;
    split >> n;
    if (op == '*')
        ans *= n;
    else if (op == '/')
        ans /= n;
    else if (op == '+')
        ans += n;
    else if(op == '-')
        ans -= n;
}
```

Comment: No it still does not fixes the error
I tried these(#2) test cases http://spojtoolkit.com/history/ARITH2